React and Chrome extension - state variable not updating from incoming message
I am working on a chrome extension written in React.  I have a button, once clicked I will update the state variable and hence switch the page.  Everything works in the action is triggered by user, but if it is triggered by the incoming message from content script, then nothing works.  For example, i would like to switch the page to About page when I receive a message from content script, I have a log statement, even I have manually clicked the button and switched to Account page, if I check the current page when I receive the message from content script, it still shows the default page which is Home, and setPage (state variable) to About does not work.
However, if I similar the button click e.g. button.click() when I receive the message from content page, then the page switches.
So what is the problem?
Here is the simplified code:
App.tsx
function App() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(PageTypes.Home.toString());
    let sidePanelScriptHelper: SidePanelScriptHelper | null = null;

    function loadActiveTabText() {
        debug("loadActiveTabText - on page " + currentPage);
        if (currentPage !== PageTypes.Home.toString()) {
                    setCounter(counter + 1);
        setCurrentPage(PageTypes.Home.toString());
        debug("Switch to HOME");
        }
    }

    function handleIncomingMessage(message: ExtMessage) {
        debug('sidepanel received message:')
        loadActiveTabText();

//            var importButton = document.getElementById("button");
//            importButton!.click(); this works
    }

    sidePanelScriptHelper = SidePanelScriptHelper.getInstance(handleIncomingMessage);

    return (

        <>
...
                <div className="d-flex" id="wrapper">
                    <div id="main">
                        <div className="container py-3">
                            {(() => {
                                if (currentPage == PageTypes.About.toString()) {
                                    return <About />
                                } else if (currentPage == PageTypes.Account.toString()) {
                                    return <Account />
                                } else {
                                    return <Home />
                                }
                            })()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <Navigation pageSwitcher={onPageChange} isLoggedIn={loggedIn} currentPage={currentPage} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
};
export default App

thanks

Could you provide a code example of how your state is updated, i assume via useEffect?

Thanks, added simplified code.

You could try to use useEffect. It would look something like this;
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(PageTypes.Home.toString());
    let sidePanelScriptHelper: SidePanelScriptHelper | null = null;

    useEffect(() => {
        sidePanelScriptHelper = SidePanelScriptHelper.getInstance(handleIncomingMessage);

        return () => {
            // Clean up the listener when component unmounts
            sidePanelScriptHelper.cleanup();
        }
    }, []);

    function loadActiveTabText() {
        debug("loadActiveTabText - on page " + currentPage);
        if (currentPage !== PageTypes.Home.toString()) {
            setCurrentPage(PageTypes.Home.toString());
            debug("Switch to HOME");
        }
    }

    function handleIncomingMessage(message: ExtMessage) {
        debug('sidepanel received message:');

        // Force state update via React's state setter
        setCurrentPage(PageTypes.About.toString());
        debug('Set currentPage to About');
    }

    return (
        ...
    
    );
}

export default App;


Thanks!  but still doesn't work.  One thing I noticed was that it worked a couple times (either put that in useEffect or outside of useEffect) then it will stop working.  Not sure what is cause that...
